# create date with semi-monthly schedule

Tags: vb.net

I created a simple Lending program that generate MONTHLY payment mode. The generated schedule is 4 periods so every month the borrower should pay. Just shown screenshot below.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub GenerateScheule()

    Dim PrincipalAmount As Double = Me.tbPrincipalAmount.Text
    Dim InterestRate As Double = Me.tbInterestRate.Text
    Dim Period As Integer = Me.tbPeriod.Text
    Dim LoanDate As Date = Me.dtpLoanDate.Text
    Dim ModePayment As String = Me.cbModeOfPayment.Text

    Me.tbLastPayment.Text = LoanDate.AddMonths(Period)

    If cbModeOfPayment.Text = "Semi-Monthly" Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To Period

            Dim dtDate As Date = LoanDate.AddMonths(i)

             dgvLoanSchedule.Rows.Add(i, Format(dtDate, "MMM/dd/yyyy"))

        Next
    End If
```

Now i want also to create a SEMI-MONTHLY payment mode. If borrowers has 4 periods it doubles up to 8 periods but in semi-monthly format. Just shown screenshot below.

Please someone help me out. I appreciate your help. Thank you guyz.

[image]

Comment: `LoanDate.AddDays(15)`?

Comment: Sorry not working. Thanks @PikoH

Comment: _Sorry not working_ doesn't seem very descriptive to me :)